# What is the new attribute for initialize_all_variables, global_variables_initializer in the latest version of tensorflow?

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow

code:

init = tf.initialize_all_variables()
init = tf.global_variables_initializer()

error:

module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'initialize_all_variables'
module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'global_variables_initializer'

Answer (score 0):

There is no `tf.initialize_all_variables` or `tf.global_variables_initializer` in TF2. See the guide: [Migrate your TensorFlow 1 code to TensorFlow 2](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/migrate)

If you want to use TF1 behavior in TF2, you can use the [`tf.compat.v1` module](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/compat/v1).